# Website response time test tool

Tags: performance, web

My manager wants to know the speed of our website and its load times in different locations of the world, according to some speed testing websites / tools.

What are the standard tools / procedures for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org) is a pretty awesome tool way more detailed than Gomez. Waterfall charts, repeat loads, and even videos of how a page loads. It has a few locations and connection speeds you can choose from. It seems to be down right now, but will probably be back up soon.

Comment: [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org) might have been fine for site testing back when everyone used a dial-up connection, but their times are so slow, random, and inaccurate nowadays (27JUN13) I refuse to take any reports of degradation seriously unless they use an accurate testing service like [GTMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com).

Comment: I believe GTMetrix uses WebPageTest agents under the hood. Secret with WPT is know which agents are reliable (I run my own), but the underlying tech is sound enough for Google to use it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

[Gomez](http://www.gomez.com) is a tools that I've used at a couple of organizations. It will monitor your site at timed intervals from a list of nodes that you select, for either an individual page or over an entire transaction (think a click-path through your website)

The reporting capabilities are really good, and you can drill down into individual page requests to identify any performance bottlenecks or issues with site performance. There's also alerting options and the list of nodes and update frequency is excellent.

I've never been involved in the actual purchasing or account management however, so I'm not sure how expensive it is.